# Share video link to facebook ios

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, video, facebook-sdk-3.1

I am working on a ios app.

I need to share a video link to facebook.Video will save on my server.

I am using below code:-

```
params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                  AppName, @"title",
                                   AppName, @"name",
                                   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",text], @"caption",
                                    composeViewController1.text, @"description",
                                    Path, @"link",
                                    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@app_icon-DEMO.png",ServerPath,URLImageFolder], @"picture",
                                   nil];
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed"
                                 parameters:params
                                 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                              if (!error) {
                                  // Link posted successfully to Facebook
                                  NSLog(@"result: %@", result);
                              } else {
                                  // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                  // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                                  NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
                              }
                          }];
```

But i am getting below error from this

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0xc52be90 {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=500, com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 1500;
            "error_subcode" = 1609005;
            message = "This link could not be posted.";
            type = FacebookApiException;
        };
    };
    code = 500;
```

But if i try to share static link say "www.google.com" it is working.

My app's flow is :-

User will check mark on facebook button and the feed will share on facebook and my app at the same time.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly whats going wrong here, but as far I know Facebook return `com.facebook.sdk code=5 the operation couldn't be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)` this error in few cases, like

1. Session is is not open.
2. Facebook has detected that you're spamming the system.
3. Facebook has a defined limit using the SDK.
4. You don't have permission to do so or wrong publish permission.

The link you have provided is not working. When I tried to open the link it's say
[image]

Facebook need to parse your url. May be that's why fb not give you to post the url.

Comment: If any of the 4 case is true how can i able to post on facebook if i remove that variable and put "www.google.com"? The problem is that static link is working but if i place any variable it is not working.

Comment: can you post the link that you are trying to post in fb